# grails multiple line in g:sortableColumn

Tags: grails

how can I do a line-break in a g:sortableColumn tag?

I tried it with

```
<g:sortableColumn property="film.name" title="Line1\nLine2" />
```

and

```
<g:sortableColumn property="film.name" title="Line1<br />Line2" />
```

but that didn't worked.

What is the right syntax for a line break?

Thanks

Comment: Try `title="${Line1\nLine2}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround would be to set a variable with the html new line tag `<br />` like this:

```
<c:set var="filmName">Line1<br />Line2</c:set>
```

And then put your variable in the column title:

```
<g:sortableColumn property="film.name" title="${filmName}" />
```